# Could not instantiate collection persister with JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Now i am development one multi-tenant system, use spring-boot with JPA and hibernate.

There is some problem when i want to persister one collection.
At the code, there have one `embeddable` class 'Account', and at `Tenant` class, have one `Set<Account>`

Tenant

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant", 
   uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "tenant_id"))
public class Tenant extends ConcurrentSafeEntity<Tenant, TenantId> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6910165036330125453L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private TenantId tenantId;

    @Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "tenant_account")
    private Set<Account> accounts;
    ...
}
```

Account

```
@Embeddable
public class Account implements ValueObject<Account> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2780296854441642870L;

    @Embedded
    private AccountNumber accountNumber;

    @Embedded
    private EncryptedPassword password;
    ...
}
```

AccountNumber

```
@Embeddable
public class AccountNumber implements ValueObject<AccountNumber> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2737145407283086518L;

    @Column(name = "account_number", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String source;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;
    ...
}
```

But when i test by

```
@Test
public void constructor() throws Exception {
    Tenant tenant = new Tenant(
            tenantRepository.nextIdentity(), "AName",
            new AccountNumber("test@wcscent.com", "email"),
            new EncryptedPassword("aPassword", encryptionService),
            validator
    );

    tenantRepository.save(tenant);
}
```

Error is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
... 24 more

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 39 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate collection persister org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:167)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:140)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:399)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879)
... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.generateSelectSizeString(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1017)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.<init>(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:504)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.BasicCollectionPersister.<init>(BasicCollectionPersister.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createCollectionPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:152)
... 49 more
```

For JPA and hibernate, I use still relatively unfamiliar. So, can you tell me, what's wrong with me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: *Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'* - where is your EMF ?

Comment: Dependent injection by spring-boot

Comment: Dependent injection by spring-boot @ScaryWombat

Comment: Would `spring-boot` dependencies get injected by Junit?

Comment: Yes, by annotation `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: And `tenantRepository` have annotation `@Autowired`, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i resolve the problem by track hibernate code. And it just because my codes don't is standard POJO.

It means properties of classes may don't have getter or setter. So hibernate cannot find them.

But i think this may be a bug. Because this situation just happened at `AccountNumber` and `EncryptedPassword`. And they are belong to `Account`.

In other words, if properties belong to `Tenant` or `Account`,   hibernate can find them, even if them don't have getter and setter. But if the properties belong to `AccountNumber` and `EncryptedPassword`, hibernate wouldn't find them when them don't have getter and setter.